# C# вопрос по преобразованию

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Есть класс, реализующий интерфейс IEnumerable

```
class MyClass : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator(); //всё хорошо
        return (IEnumerable)this.GetEnumerator(); //error;
    }
```

Почему первый вариант компилятор принимает, а второй подчеркивает, что такая запись недопустима, если, по идеи, оба эти записи являются операциями преобразования?

Comment: GetEnume**n**ator != GetEnume**r**ator

Comment: @Igor Не особо понимаю Ваш ответ.

Comment: Всмотритесь внимательно в строчку с `//error;`

Comment: @Igor Это незначительная синтаксическая ошибка, это моя опечатка просто

Comment: Опечатка где? Здесь или в коде?

Comment: @Igor Здесь именно, в коде все правильно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80672/discussion-between-castiel-luciefer2000-and-igor).

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000 ну так исправьте опечатку и не вводите людей в заблуждение! (кнопка править, под вопросом)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что он думает, что Вы хотите переменную типа `IEnumerable` преобразовать в `IEnumerator`. То есть расценивает это как попытку вызвать `this.GetEnumerator()`, преобразовать реультат в `IEnumerable` (явным кастом) и вернуть как `IEnumerator` (неявным кастом) - тип возвращаемого значения, объявленный в декларации метода. Просто:

```
return this.GetEnumerator();
```

Answer (score 4):

В первом случае вы приводите к типу `IEnumerable` свой `this`:

```
return ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator();
```

Во втором случае вы приводите к типу  `IEnumerable` результат `this.GetEnumenator()`

```
return (IEnumerable)this.GetEnumenator();
```

Поэтому и ошибка. А вообще, вы можете тут написать вот так:

```
return GetEnumerator(); // это тоже не вызовет ошибки
```